# retriving messages from pop3 server

Tags: java, pop3, jakarta-mail

i'm making a little application to download messages from pop3 server using the javax.mail library, i check for new messages saving the date of the last message i downloaded from pop3 but i get a problem with the getMessages() function:
if i do getMessages().length i always get 0 if there are no new messages so i can't re-download old messages..

here is my code for example:

```
pop3Store = (POP3Store) pop3Session.getStore("pop3");
pop3Store.connect(cPOP3HostName, aPOP3UserName, aPOP3Password);
pop3Folder = (POP3Folder) pop3Store.getFolder("INBOX");
pop3Folder.open(2);
messages = pop3Folder.getMessages();
for (int index = 0; index < messages.length; index++) {
    ....//date check for messages[index]
}
```

i get messages.length > 0 only if i get NEW messages on my pop3server.. so I can't download two times the same message..

Do you have any ideas about?
I'm trying my code using GMAIL as pop3 server.

I hope to was clear explaining my problem,
thanks to all

Regards
Luca

Answer (score 0):

i've solved using the pop3settings of gmail.
1) disabling pop3
2) setting pop3 to download all messages